# Problem In Delete Row Functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to create a functionality of deleting a row but getting an error Invalid Id...

controller:

```
public String sel_id{get;set;}
public void DeleteRow()
{
    Color_Coding__c cc = new Color_Coding__c(id=sel_id);
    delete cc;
}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
<td><apex:commandLink action="{!DeleteRow}" value="Delete" reRender="color, id" immediate="true">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!sel_id}" value="" name="id"/>
    </apex:commandLink></td>
```

Comment: your `value` attribute is empty in your VF code is it?

Comment: @highfive yeah its empty what do I have do in it ???

Comment: You have to add the value to be assigned into `sel_id`

Comment: @highfive thanx man (Y)